# Xcode object type popup equivalent in AppCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

Does AppCode have an equivalent for the Xcode feature below to show the object type? I found this popup quite helpful when trying to identify optionals.

`(option + click)`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar actions in AppCode are:

- Quick Documentation (F1): shows type, declaration and documentation, if any
- Quick Definition (Option+Space): shows where and how the variable is defined
- Cmd+Mouse hover - shows a small pop-up

Comment: awesome! that worked. Also remapped it to my opt + click. Thank you!